# use service as decorator

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

Is there a way to do a static decorator on routes that check certain logics before loading?
example

have a auth decorator

```
@Injector()
class Auth{
    Auth(){
        if (isLoggedIn){
        proceed();
    }else{
       showLoginRoute();
    }
   }
}
```

and use like

```
@Auth()
@Component(
   selector: 'auth-view',
   styleUrls: const ['login_component.css'],
   template:
          '<router-outlet name="dashboard" [routes]="routes.authView_routes"></router-outlet>',
   directives: const [materialDirectives, routerDirectives, coreDirectives],
      providers: const [r.Routes, materialProviders, Auth],
)
class Dashboard{
    ....
}
```

I know what i want to do but just not sure how to get it done. Currently  i am importing services across several components and doing lots of repetition and i want to avoid that as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Dart doesn't support anything like decorators in TS.

What might work for you is code generation like it's done in `build_value`, `json_serializable`, ...

https://github.com/dart-lang/build

Comment: so is there no other way to get the desired result im looking for?

Comment: There is nothing like what these decorators can in JS/TS. Another way might be to implementing some stuff in a subclass and inheriting the widget from such a class.